# Could not initialize MySQL client library in Justhost

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails, redmine

I am trying to configure redmine in justhost. following link was used for configuration. 
Link: https://my.justhost.com/cgi/help/redmine
I am getting error - Could not initialize MySQL client library.

How to resolve this issue.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LEta.jpg)